# How can I find the radius of this circle. Versine, x, and theta are known. (diagram included)

Tags: trigonometry, circles

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpYPt.png)

So we know the versine length, and we know the length of x (blue line). We also know the angle theta. From this information it is simple to find the lengths of the dotted blue/green line (idk if we need that info or not). **How can I find the radius of this circle?** I am pretty sure that I can find the radius if I can find L, so maybe that is a necessary intermediate step.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to not link in diagrams

Comment: Is it possible to embed diagrams?

Comment: Yes, import pictures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets $v$ be versine, and $R$ be the radius.

By the law of cosines.

$R^2 = (R-v)^2 + x^2 + 2(R-v)x\cos\theta$

And solve for $R$

$R = \frac {v^2 + x^2 - 2vx\cos\theta}{2v-2x\cos\theta}$

Comment: This seems to work! Thank you, Doug.

Answer (score 0):

By Law of Cosines, $R^2 = x^2 + (R-v)^2 + 2x(R-v)\cos\theta$.

Solving this should give your solution.

Comment: Oops, my bad, I'll fix that